# Assembly register compares (8086)

Tags: assembly, compare, ascii, x86-16

I am new to assembly and creating a program that takes a value in the `AX` register, say `F43A`, and converts it to its ascii string in decimal.

For instance, `AX = 8EFFh` would print out `-28929`.  (Convert 2s complement to ascii)

I am having trouble with comprehending the registers.  Do I have to convert the `AX` register to decimal first, or is that implied that if `AX = 000Ah` in hex that `AX` is also equal to 10 in decimal.

So does

```
mov AX,000Ah
cmp AX,10
```

work?

Any help would be appreciated.  We will be using the reduction of powers algorithm, which will be based off the decimal value of `AX`.  Though the input value of `AX` will be in Hex.

If that doesn't work, how would I get the decimal value out of `AX`?

Comment: Please mind that when you are referring hex values put them as 0x000A or 000Ah

Answer (score 1):

CPUs fundamentally know only binary. The assembler, compiler or disassembler only provide convenience utilities to assist inputting or outputting the data in higher levels of abstraction (such as grouping to hex-digits or decimals, signed or unsigned, floating points and *instructions* such as `cmp ax, 10`).

Both `cmp ax, 10` and some variety of `cmp ax, 0x0a` or `cmp ax, $a` or `cmp ax, 000ah` all encode to the same instruction: `xx 0a`.

Your task indeed is using instructions knowing only "numbers" split a 16-bit number (e.g. 8EFF) to it's components (array of length 1..5) and output it using ASCII conversion.

When implementing the reduction of powers algorithm, notice that the [8086 DIV instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028561/assembly-division/13028693#13028693) use the register pair DX:AX as the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the digits in reverse order by dividing by 10, then the remainder is the last digit, then divide by 10 again, the remainder is the next to last digit, ...

or you can divide by 10,000 and the quotient is the first digit unless it's zero. Then divide the remainder by 1000, and the quotient is the next digit, ...